# Installing OpenSuSE on a raid drive system

Tags: opensuse

Anyone know a guide or are able to assist me in installing OpenSuSE on my computer. I have two SSD's configured in a raid (Intel Storage Matrix). 2x120GB.  I have two partitions on it, one 140GB where windows is installed, and the rest have not been assigned any partition yet. (was planing on installing OpenSuSE on it.

What happens. It detects the Intel Storage Matrix and asks if it should use it. I accept.

I then go over the basic install steps and when I come to the part where im to select the partion where to install i get stuck.

I get all my drives listed , /dev/sda , b, c ,d . a and b are the two SSD's and (c,d) are two normal drives(1.8 GB's) in raid 1 also. c and d should be left as they are.

Then it also list some entries like /dev/md124 /dev/md124p1 , p2, p3, p4, p5.

md124 is 3.6TB (assume this is the full raid of drive c and d.
md124p1 is 128mb
md124p2 is 2TB (this fits a partition i made in windows). (I only allocated 2TB of the 3.6).
md124p3-5 is (2GB,20GB,1.62TB) I assume this is the rest of my drive c and d.

I cant find the partition of the remaining 100GB of the raid 1 of two SSD's.

I havent tried anything yet as i would like some feedback here before messing with my partitions.

Comment: puzzling abit with it. I can see hte partitions on the mechanic drives, the 2TB partition and the rest not partitioned. But when looking at the SSD's they just show up as 240gb unallocated. When looking in windows, it sees the partitions just fine.

Comment: THe mechanic drives are using ReFS and the SSD's NTFS.

Comment: I just discovered that at the start of the install it detects the Intel Matrix Storage Manager. Then it lists MD compatible Raid Devices. Here only the mechanic drives are detected and not the SSD's, that must be why it cant see them later on.